Different points after conversion from SITK image to VTK Image
I am trying to convert a SITK image with its corresponding spacing, origin, and direction metadata into a VTK Image, with a conversion to a Numpy array in between.
However, when I try to grab a point within the VTK image (for reference, ( 0, 0, 0 ) ), I am finding a discrepancy in where that point is located. Is there something that I'm not doing properly when converting to the VTK image?
image = vtkImageData()
image.SetDimensions( sitkDimensions )
image.SetSpacing( sitkSpacing )
image.SetDirectionMatrix( sitkDirectionMatrix )
image.SetOrigin( sitkOrigin )
image.GetPointData().SetScalars( numpy_to_vtk( array.ravel() ) )
image.Modified()

When I print the spacing, origin, and direction matrix, they are the same between SITK and VTK, so I am really confused as to where I went wrong.

From [SimpleITKUtilities][1,2]:
def sitk2vtk(image: sitk.Image) -> vtk.vtkImageData:
"""Convert a 2D or 3D SimpleITK image to a VTK image.

VTK versions prior to version 9 do not support a direction cosine
matrix. If the installed version is lower than that, the direction
cosine matrix is ignored and that information is lost. A warning
is issued using the Python logging mechanism.

VTK images are fundamentally 3D, so 2D images are made 3D with
a Z dimension of 1.

:param image: Image to convert.
:return: A VTK image.
"""

size = list(image.GetSize())
if len(size) > 3:
    raise ValueError(
        "Conversion only supports 2D and 3D images, got {len(size)}D image"
    )

origin = image.GetOrigin()
spacing = image.GetSpacing()
direction = image.GetDirection()
ncomp = image.GetNumberOfComponentsPerPixel()

# VTK expects 3-dimensional image parameters
if len(size) == 2:
    size.append(1)
    origin = origin + (0.0,)
    spacing = spacing + (1.0,)
    direction = [
        direction[0],
        direction[1],
        0.0,
        direction[2],
        direction[3],
        0.0,
        0.0,
        0.0,
        1.0,
    ]

# Create VTK image and set its metadata
vtk_image = vtk.vtkImageData()
vtk_image.SetDimensions(size)
vtk_image.SetSpacing(spacing)
vtk_image.SetOrigin(origin)
vtk_image.SetExtent(0, size[0] - 1, 0, size[1] - 1, 0, size[2] - 1)
if vtk.vtkVersion.GetVTKMajorVersion() < 9:
    logger.warning(
        "VTK version <9 does not support direction matrix which is ignored"
    )
else:
    vtk_image.SetDirectionMatrix(direction)

# Set pixel data
depth_array = vtknp.numpy_to_vtk(sitk.GetArrayFromImage(image).ravel())
depth_array.SetNumberOfComponents(ncomp)
vtk_image.GetPointData().SetScalars(depth_array)

vtk_image.Modified()
return vtk_image


I've seen this library before, and I think my code replicated the functionalities adequately. Do you have another suggestion?
